# EJB injection in Servlet with glassfish4

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, glassfish-4.1

I have a servlet class, that worked fine with glassfish3 and Java-7.

The ear contains these resources:

- x.ear

  - x.war
  - x-interface.jar
  - x-ejb.jar

The Servlet inside the war file looks like this:

```
@Path("/X")
@ManagedBean
public class XWebservice {

    @EJB
    SessionBeanRemoteInterface bean;

    @GET
    public String get() {
        return bean.sessionBeanMethod();
    }
}
```

The bean inside the ejb-jar looks like this:

```
@Stateless
public class XBean implements SessionBeanRemoteInterface {
}
```

Why does this not work in glassfish 4.1.1 using Java-8 anymore? (NullPointerException, bean is null)

Manual lookup, however works fine:

```
new InitialContext().lookup(SessionBeanRemoteInterface.class.getName()).sessionBeanMethod();
```

Comment: Can you add what the actual error message is from GlassFish?

Comment: @Mike it is a NullPointerException here: `bean.sessionBeanMethod()`. If I print the value of `bean`, then the output is `null`.

Comment: Have you tried using `@EJB(lookup="...")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the `@RequestScoped` annotation to the Webservice.

Alternatively `@Singleton` seems also to work.

Answer (score 0):

How many implementations do you have? If more then one, then use qualifiers (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html) or alternatives (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjsdf.html). If the container unable to choose the injection does not work.